# Identify BM 64 diodes (SMD)

Tags: diodes, identification

I need help to identify these BM 64 diodes, I can't see any polarity band, D4,5,6 written on PCB. Could they be DIACs?
Seems the designed to protect data lines between ethernet connector & display touch screen ( the White connector.

I measured with Fluke @ 'Diode' they all show 'O.L' both directions.

[3× suspected MB64 diodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhe6d.jpg)

Comment: DONI tech - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification, especially photos of the PCB, including close to the unknown components and a wider view, showing lots more of the surrounding circuitry. If there is no polarity marking on the diodes, then that allows another type of diode as a possibility. Seeing the nearby circuitry will help to confirm / deny that possibility. Please edit the question to add photos. Thanks.

Comment: DO-214 ?.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are Vishay [SMBJ15CA](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj.pdf) bidirectional TVS diodes.

The logo is frequently used on Vishay didoes, hence the manufacturer decision. The image below is a generic image of such a diode to Vishay showing the logo they use.

The package size matches, SMB (DO-214AA), at 4.3mm long x 3.5mm wide, with wrap-under leads.

The marking is BM, *not* MB. Which indicates a 15V bidirectional variant from their SMBJ series.

The 64 will be a [date code](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf).

[image: Vishay Date Code Information]

The lack of a cathode marking band is due to the fact that it is a bidirectional TVS diode (two diodes in anti-series - cathode to cathode internally), and so will not have the cathode marker per the notes.

Furthermore, the `Z` digit again per the notes is optional. Yours doesn't have it, but it has the `XY` correctly positioned to the left of the package.

Comment: Thank's fir the full answer,

Comment: Did you just memorize all the logos over your career or is there some reference list or search engine somewhere?

Comment: @KH just one I'm familiar with. I've never found a complete list anywhere.